# outer join more than 2 tables in access

Tags: ms-access, outer-join

After following [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28095/joining-3-tables-using-sql-query/) thread. I am getting an error as "Syntax Error in JOIN Operation"

Here Is my query

```
SELECT 
    StudentMaster.Student_id, 
    ExamDetails.Subject_id, 
    SubjectMaster.Subject_id 
FROM 
    (StudentMaster 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ExamDetails 
       ON StudentMaster.Student_id = ExamDetails.Student_id) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ExamDetails 
      ON SubjectMaster.subject_id = ExamDetails.Subject_id
```

Any help regarding this would be appreciable

Comment: what you want the result from table.

Comment: You have `ON SubjectMaster.subject_id = ...` but no `SubjectMaster` table defined in the `FROM` clause (but you have joined `ExamDetails` twice). I guess the 2nd join should be `LEFT OUTER JOIN  SubjectMaster`

Comment: i want list of students as well as subjects associated to student along with records from examdetails

Comment: Could it be the brackets that are causing a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one.

```
select s.Student_id,e.Subject_id,sub.Subject_id
from YourDatabaseName.SubjectMaster as sub 
left outer join YourDatabaseName.ExamDetails as e 
    on sub.Subject_id=e.Subject_id
left outer join YourDatabaseName.StudentMaster as s
    on s.Student_id=e.Student_id
group by s.Student_id
order by s.Student_id;
```